# Changing heading font size misaligns divs

Tags: html, css

I've recently started doing frontend and I've run into a bit of a problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10%;
  height: 40px;
}

.head-title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em; /* Changing this to 1em fixes the problem */
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.head-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=header>
      <div class="head-title"><p>Amazing Title</p></div>
      <div class="head-button"><p>Foo</p></div>
      <div class="head-button"><p>Bar</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can run the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/42n9owpy/1). The problem is with aligning the red buttons with the navbar (`header`). The buttons are supposed to stretch from the top to the bottom of the navbar, but they aren't aligned to the top. This is caused by the `head-title` element. If the font size is set to 1em, then the problem disappears. Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set `vertical-align: top;` on the `.head-button`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10%;
  height: 40px;
}

.head-title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* Changing this to 1em fixes the problem */
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.head-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  <div class="head-title">
    <p>Amazing Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **vertical-align: top;** to **.head-button** class so the blocks will be aligned to top.

```
.head-button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use modern solution and *!coding* not a property such `display: inline-block` or `vertical-align: top` that almost is old and obsolete, in this case when you want to put element side by side and align them in a certain row you can use `flex` on their parents like below example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    background: white;
    padding: 0 10%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.head-title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* Changing this to 1em fixes the problem */
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.head-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  <div class="head-title">
    <p>Amazing Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*With `flex` you can control parent and also child alignments! something like `justify-content: center;` or `align-items: center;`*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:flex` css property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header {
    background: white;
    padding: 0 10%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .head-title {
    font-size: 1.3em; /* Changing this to 1em fixes the problem */
    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  .head-button {
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #24272E;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class=header>
  <div class="head-title"><p>Amazing Title</p></div>
  <div class="head-button"><p>Foo</p></div>
  <div class="head-button"><p>Bar</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  padding: 0 10%;
  height: 40px;
}

.head-title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* Changing this to 1em fixes the problem */
  width: 260px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.head-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
}

/** My Code **/
.head-title {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 260px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.head-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
  <div class="head-title">
    <p>Amazing Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="head-button">
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```